# How to have persistant database using alasql

Tags: javascript, alasql

I've try this on Codepen:

```
var result = db.exec('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MyBase; \
                      ATTACH INDEXEDDB DATABASE MyBase;\
                      USE MyBase;'+command)[3];
```

but after first command I've got exception that database exists, if I don't use create database I've got error that database don't exists

if I've call `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MyBase` ones at the beginning then I've got error that table don't exist even that I've called create table.

If I've use:

```
CREATE INDEXEDDB DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MyBase
```

I've got error that database don't exists.

I've also tried to execute:

```
window.indexedDB.open("MyBase", 3);
```

but that also don't work.

And if I don't use indexDB the tables are cleared after refresh.

Here is my codepen https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/dVBaRm?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index db require async code:

```
alasql('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MyBase; \
        ATTACH INDEXEDDB DATABASE MyBase;\
        USE MyBase;', [], function() {
    alasql(command, [], function(res) {
    });
});
```

it's on the wiki  https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/IndexedD